# How to speed up nested loop of lookup operations?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, opencv, nested-loops

I am programming the [halftoning of images for laser-engraving](https://github.com/miguelmorin/halftone). At a given setting, the laser only turns on or off, so I can give it binary images with 1-bit depth. So I convert grayscale images with 8-bit depth (0 to 255) to binary images with 1-bit depth (0 to 1).

I include two images below as an example. The left is a grayscale image. The right is the result of replacing each pixel with a 3x3 square of binary pixels. The result looks similar because the gray comes from the density of the black pixels.

[image: Original sample in grayscale]
[image: Output of sample image with binary pixels]

My current attempt uses a nested loop to access the pixels and replaces the pixels in the output image with a looked-up value in a dictionary:

```py
import math
import time

import numpy as np

TONES = [[0, 0,
          0, 0],
         [0, 1,
          0, 0],
         [1, 1,
          0, 0],
         [1, 1,
          0, 1],
         [1, 1,
          1, 1]]

def process_tones():
    """Converts the tones above to the right shape."""
    tones_dict = dict()

    for t in TONES:
        brightness = sum(t)
        bitmap_tone = np.reshape(t, (2, 2)) * 255
        tones_dict[brightness] = bitmap_tone
    return(tones_dict)

def halftone(gray, tones_dict):
    """Generate a new image where each pixel is replaced by one with the values in tones_dict.
    """

    num_rows = gray.shape[0]
    num_cols = gray.shape[1]
    num_tones = len(tones_dict)
    tone_width = int(math.sqrt(num_tones - 1))

    output = np.zeros((num_rows * tone_width, num_cols * tone_width),
                         dtype = np.uint8)

    # Go through each pixel
    for i in range(num_rows):
        i_output = range(i * tone_width, (i + 1)* tone_width)

        for j in range(num_cols):
            j_output = range(j * tone_width, (j + 1)* tone_width)

            pixel = gray[i, j]
            brightness = int(round((num_tones - 1) * pixel / 255))

            output[np.ix_(i_output, j_output)] = tones_dict[brightness]

    return output

def generate_gray_image(width = 100, height = 100):
    """Generates a random grayscale image.
    """

    return (np.random.rand(width, height) * 256).astype(np.uint8)

gray = generate_gray_image()
tones_dict = process_tones()

start = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    binary = halftone(gray, tones_dict = tones_dict)
duration = time.time() - start
print("Average loop time: " + str(duration))
```

The result is:

```
Average loop time: 3.228989839553833
```

The average loop takes 3 seconds for a 100x100 image, which seems long compared to OpenCV's functions

I checked [How to speed-up python nested loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065624/how-to-speed-up-python-nested-loop) and [Looping over pixels in an image](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192739/looping-over-pixels-in-an-image) and I don't immediately see how to vectorize this operation.

How can I speed up this nested loop of lookup operations?

Comment: You could use a compiled language.  Python isn't the best tool for everything.

Comment: You should provide some sample data and expected output. [MCVE]

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output. Your requirement doesn't even look like it would need a nested for loop if you're using numpy

Comment: In addition to some sample data, just explaining what you're trying to do in a bit more detail would help. There are many ways to "fill an output array with [a] lookup value based on the gray value of the pixels."

Comment: If you're looking for speed, I would delete the `if` block that contains the `print` statement, to start

Comment: @C.Nivs Indeed, deleting that check in the new minimal example brings the loop duration from 13 seconds to 3.

Comment: @Alexander and others: I added a minimal reproducible example and an explanation of my goal.

Comment: The output can be considered a combination of 4 subimages of the same size as the original (one each for top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right position on the halftone grid). Then it's a matter of pre-calculating 4 lookup tables, performing the lookup. Finally you combine the 4 subimages using a combination of numpy reshape and stack operations.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to not iterate at such low granularity as you do, but instead offload most of the work to optimized numpy functions.

---

Conceptually, we can treat the output image, as a collection of smaller images (call them "channels"), each holding data for one of the positions in the half-tone grid.

[image]

The individual channel images can then be generated by a simple lookup, which in Numpy we can simply do by [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) the lookup table with the grayscale image (i.e. `LUT[image]`).

### Lookup Tables

Let's say we define the "tile size" (size of one half-tone pattern), and the individual tone tiles in the following manner:

```
TILE_SIZE = (2, 2) # Rows, Cols

TONES = np.array(
    [[0, 0,
      0, 0],
     [0, 1,
      0, 0],
     [1, 1,
      0, 0],
     [1, 1,
      0, 1],
     [1, 1,
      1, 1]]
    , dtype=np.uint8) * 255
```

We first use [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) to calculate the mapping between grayscale and tone indices.
Then for each position, we create the lookup table from the definition of tones (using the lookup technique to do so).

```
def generate_LUTs(tones, tile_size):
    num_tones, num_tiles = tones.shape
    tile_rows, tile_cols = tile_size
    assert(num_tiles == (tile_rows * tile_cols))

    # Generate map between grayscale value and tone index
    gray_level = np.linspace(0, (num_tones - 1), 256, dtype=np.float32)
    tone_map = np.uint8(np.round(gray_level))

    # Generate lookup tables for each tile
    LUTs = []
    for tile in range(num_tiles):
        LUTs.append(tones[:,tile][tone_map])

    return LUTs
```

### Merging Channels

Now, to merge the channels together into a complete output image.

First step is to [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) each channel image, such that it has only one column.

Then, we can combine all the channel images that share the same half-tone pattern row using [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html).

[image]

Next, we reshape the results, such that they have the same number of rows as the input image (i.e. they will now have twice as many columns).

We combine all the reshaped images again using [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html).

[image]

Finally, we reshape the result such that is has the correct number of rows (according to the tile size), and we're done.

[image]

In code (generalized for any tile size):

```
def halftone(image, LUTs, tile_size):
    tiles = []
    for tile in range(len(LUTs)):
        tiles.append(LUTs[tile][image])

    image_rows, _ = image.shape
    tile_rows, tile_cols = tile_size

    merged_rows = []
    for row in range(tile_rows):
        row_tiles = tiles[row * tile_cols:(row + 1) * tile_cols]
        merged_row = np.hstack([row_tile.reshape(-1, 1) for row_tile in row_tiles])
        merged_rows.append(merged_row.reshape(image_rows, -1))

    return np.hstack(merged_rows).reshape(image_rows * tile_rows, -1)
```

---

**Example use:**

```
LUTs = generate_LUTs(TONES, TILE_SIZE)
binary = halftone(gray, LUTs, TILE_SIZE)
```

---

**Example output:**

[image]

And with 3x3 tiles:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solve very fast with pure numpy.

- First compute `brightness` in vectorized way.
- Next index `tones` with brightness to transform `gray` to 4d array of shape HxWx2x2
- use `np.transpose` to reorganize array to interleave introduced dimensions from `tones` with original ones from `gray`. The image is transformed to Hx2xWx2
- "flatten/merge" vertical dimensions (H-from `gray` and 2 from `tone`), do the same for horizontal dimensions (W from `gray`, 2 from `tone`). This operation is done by reshaping to (H*2)x(W*2)

Please paste following code below the code from the question and run it.

```
def process_tones2():
    tones = np.array(TONES, dtype='u1')
    size = int(np.sqrt(tones.shape[-1]))
    tones = 255 * tones.reshape(-1, size, size)
    bins = tones.sum(axis=(-2,-1), dtype=int) // size ** 2
    iperm = np.argsort(bins)
    return bins[iperm], tones[iperm]

def halftone_fast(gray, bins, tones):
    height, width = gray.shape
    tone_height, tone_width = tones.shape[-2:]
    brightness = np.round(gray / 255 * (len(tones) - 1)).astype('u1')
    binary4d = tones[brightness]
    binary4d = binary4d.transpose((0,2,1,3))
    binary = binary4d.reshape(height * tone_height, width * tone_width)
    return binary

bins, tones = process_tones2()
start = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    binary2 = halftone_fast(gray, bins, tones)
duration = time.time() - start
print("Average loop time: " + str(duration))
print("Error:", np.linalg.norm(binary.astype(float) - binary2))
```

On my machine I got following results:

```
Average loop time: 2.3393328189849854
Average loop time: 0.0032405853271484375
Error: 0.0
```

Speed up is about 1000x.

Note that argument `bins` is not used in `halftone_fast()`. The reason is that it is not needed for halftoning. The code is the question works only if `TONES` form a linear space of brightness levels starting from 0 ending on all ones. Therefore `brightness` works as an index to a sorted list of `tones`.

If the mapping wat not linear that ones would have to use `np.digitize(gray, bins)` to compute proper indices in `tones` array.

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm appears to have two parts: computation of the "brightness" of each pixel, and replacement of the pixels by the halftone dots.

First, I'll assume that the input image has shape (*h*, *w*).

```
grayscale = np.array(...)
h, w = grayscale.shape
```

#### Brightness levels

Computing brightness has two steps:

1. Determine the bounds for each brightness level. This can be achieved by using [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) to divides the range [0, 256) into `num_tones` equal-sized chunks.

   ```
   bins = np.linspace(0, 256, num_tones + 1)
   # e.g. with 4 tones: [0, 64, 128, 192, 256]
   ```
2. Determine which level each pixel falls in. This can be achieved using [`np.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html#numpy.digitize).

   ```
   # (subtract 1 because digitize counts from 1)
   levels = np.digitize(grayscale, bins) - 1  # shape (h, w)
   ```

   Then `levels[i, j]` is the brightness level of `grayscale[i,j]` (from 0 to `num_tones`, inclusive).

#### Halftones

Now that you have the brightness levels of each pixel, you can use those as keys to get their halftone matrices. To make this as easy as possible, you'll want the halftones in a Numpy array, instead of a dictionary.

```
tones = np.array(...)  # shape(num_tones, x, y)
x, y = tones.shape[1:]
```

By using the image's brightness levels as an [index array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays)<sup>1</sup> for `tones`, you get each pixel's halftone matrix.

```
halftones = tones[levels]  # shape (h, w, x, y)
# halftones[i, j] is the halftone for grayscale[i, j]
```

Then it's just a matter of getting the elements in the right order and flattening the array.

```
# Reorder axes so halftone rows are before image columns
ordered = halftones.swapaxes(1, 2)  # shape (h, x, w, y)

# Make it 2-dimensional
result = ordered.reshape(h * x, w * y)
```

#### Speed

I wrote [a script](https://gist.github.com/jirassimok/de4b5799a776da951fa50156f304c85e) to compare the speeds of the original code, my answer, and [tstanisl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58792441). The results:

```
Best times
halftone:      0.346237126000000
np_halftone:   0.000565907715000
halftone_fast: 0.000437084295000
```

Both answers run a few hundred (600 for mine, 800 for tstanisl's) times faster than the original code, with tstanisl's doing better than mine by about 30%.

In exchange for that speed, my function has one minor advantages of tstanisl's and the original: if you want to use custom tones that do not have total values corresponding directly to their brightness, this algorithm will still work (e.g. if you want to invert the colors in the halftone). Otherwise, tstanisl's is more efficient.

---

<sup>1</sup> The last example in the linked section of the Numpy user guide is actually very similar to this—it talks about mapping image color values to RGB triples.

Comment: Nice approach, with using a 4-d array and then swapping the axes. Much more concise than my explicit stacking.