# Multithread/process to speed up a function inside double loops?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, for-loop, multiprocessing

I am trying to do something like this:

```
import skimage  

def dostuff(im, [m, n]):
    # im is a 2D numpy array greyscale image.
    # This calculate the line profile from a given point [m,n] 
    # to the origin [0, 0] on the im
    line = skimage.measure.profile_line(im, [m,n], [0,0])
    first_two = line[:2]
    return first_two 

x = 20
matrix = np.zeros(2*x+1, 2*x+1, 1000) 
for m in range(-x, x+1):
    for n in range(-x, x+1):
        result = dostuff(im, [m,n])
        matrix[m, n] = result
```

Is there any way by using multithreading or multiprocessing in python to speed up this double loop calculation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to speed-up python nested loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065624/how-to-speed-up-python-nested-loop)

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to give you an answer. Depends on type of computation `dostuff()` is doing and the type and size of the arguments and return value, for example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my omittion. I have update the question with detailed function I was trying to do inside the nested loop.